# Triac Equivalence

Tags: transistors, components, triac, board

I was troubleshooting an infant radiant warmer having little output voltage to the radiator power outlet and I did a continuity test on a triac and it's a dead component.
I don't know the equivalence of this. I need help here.

Specifications are:
BTA16-600B
GK02V VU
CHN 607

[image: Triac]

Comment: how did you measure the continuity?

Comment: Just search for BTA16-600, there will be plenty of hits on Google as it's a very common part. That is, of course, if it's dead - which is a big if.

Comment: Usually triacs fail 'on'.